# How to change the mark (*) color in dired mode

Tags: dired, faces

I am using the cyberpunk-theme, the * are show in light green and is not visible in hightlighted line. I tried to set dired-mark-face to white. Is there other variables I can set?

Comment: This is not the exact same question, but the nature is the exact same: "How do I change the foo face in bar?": http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2394/115

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set face variables directly. You should edit them with `set-face-attribute` and accompanying commands.

```
(set-face-attribute face frame &rest args)
```

- `face` - the font face you want to edit
- `frame` - whether to make the edit frame-local (nil means global, otherwise supply a specific frame)
- `args` - the individual properties to set, in the form `:property new-value`

In your example, you want to edit `dired-mark-face` to make it a different colour, and you want the change to be global:

```
(set-face-attribute 'diredp-flag-mark nil 
                    :foreground "white")
```

You can view the full documentation [here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) There are also standalone commands to set individual face attributes, such as `set-face-foreground`. You can view them [here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html)

If you see a font you would like to change, you can get information about it by hovering over it and calling the command `M-x describe-face`. The prompt will default to the face under point. You can also get more verbose information by calling `M-x what-cursor-position`

Comment: A tiny correction, the face name is diredp-flag-mark.

Comment: Good point! Should have tested that really. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the face, not the variable:

```el
(set-face-foreground 'dired-mark "#fff")
```

Comment: It will be useful for @godblessfq to figure out how to use `C-u C-x =` to know more about the character at point (face, unicode, overlays, etc): http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2394/115